# Changing destination of a printer in lp in linux

Tags: linux, printing

When I type lpstat -p in bash I get:

```
    lp@linuxbox 'xerox printer in room 100' (dest lp@193.233.9.7)
```

How do I change dest to another IP?

Answer (score 2):

Printers for plain vanilla `lpd` are configured in `/etc/printcap` - the printcap(5) man page has all the gory details on that.

Your distribution is probably using [CUPS](http://www.cups.org) though (you mentioned `lpadmin`), so you need to make your changes through the CUPS tools.  You can remove and re-add the printer via lpadmin, or see if the CUPS web interface is enabled and will let you do what you want (it's typically [http://localhost:631](http://localhost:631/))

Answer (score 0):

You don't. You add another printer at the address of interest.

Comment: Can I do it somehow rather than with lpadmin?